# Dockerfile can't copy files. ("cp" command)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile contains some `cp` linux commands.
Because some files in project are decalred as sample such as `xxx.php.sample`, and it should be replaced as `xxx.php`.

I thought this process should be executed on `Dockerfile`. So i wrote like this.

Dockerfile-php-apache

```
FROM php:5.5-apache
RUN apt-get update && \
  docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli mbstring
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod substitute
ADD . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN cp config.php.sample config.php
RUN cp shared_config.php.sample shared_config.php
RUN cp vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties.sample vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties
RUN sed -i -E "s/host=(.*);/host=mysql-db;/" ./vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties
COPY docker-php-apache/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql-db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mysql-server
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  php-apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php-apache
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
```

After `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` (No error happened), here is the `cp` results.

> RUN cp config.php.sample config.php -> **config.php is not found**
>   RUN cp shared_config.php.sample shared_config.php -> **shared_config.php is not found**
>   RUN cp vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties.sample vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties -> **build.properties is not found**

I thought the path was wrong, so i copied the above commands and executed it directly.  (I could login the container by `docker exec -it xxx_php-apache_1 bash`.)
The `cp` command finely worked and i could find the copied file in the container and my local source.

Does anyone figure out why `cp` command on Dockerfile doesn't work?

---

Here is the corresponds build log.

```
Step 5 : COPY config.php.sample /var/www/config.php
 ---> afa7e6139049
Removing intermediate container 38b9968ac061
Step 6 : COPY shared_config.php.sample /var/www/shared_config.php
 ---> 78ea51045d4e
Removing intermediate container fe0b382914bd
Step 7 : COPY vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties.sample /var/www/vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties
 ---> 34c186a193c0
Removing intermediate container c55bb9565035
Step 8 : COPY docker-php-apache/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
 ---> 4e3e92aa0f97
Removing intermediate container f2c424eb6c38
Successfully built 4e3e92aa0f97
```

---

Just in case, I executed `find` command on container.

```
root@d98556ed051a:/var/www# find / -iname '*shared_config.php*' 
/var/www/shared_config.php.sample
```

---

In addition, I tested with another laptop, but the result was same.
These are tested PCs.

- Mac mini (Mid 2011) OS X Yosemite
- Mac book pro (Late 2011) OS X Sierra

Each PC is using  Docker for Mac
Version 1.12.1 (build: 12133)

Answer (score 4):

**Approach #1**
I believe that the below statements of the `Dockerfile` can be changed
**From:**

```
ADD . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN cp config.php.sample config.php
RUN cp shared_config.php.sample shared_config.php
RUN cp vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties.sample vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties
```

**To:**

```
ADD config.php.sample /var/www/config.php
ADD shared_config.php.sample /var/www/shared_config.php
ADD vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties.sample /var/www/vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties
```

Of course, you also use `COPY` instead of `ADD` as well in the above.

**Approach #2**
Change below statements from:

```
RUN cp config.php.sample config.php
RUN cp shared_config.php.sample shared_config.php
RUN cp vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties.sample vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties
```

To:

```
RUN ["cp",  "config.php.sample", "config.php"]
RUN ["cp", "shared_config.php.sample", "shared_config.php"]
RUN ["cp", "vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties.sample", "vendor/propel/propel1/build.properties"]
```

For more details, refer [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for showing me two approaches. I tested both of ways, however did not work. At Approach #1, i could see all source codes were copied on container and WORKDIR(The initial location when i login) was changed to /var/www/html (Hmm... Shouldn't it be /var/www as docker-compose.yml describes?). At Approach #2, i realized you misspelled ' and " at the third line, so corrected and tested.

Comment: @dosuken123, thank you for ithe feedback. It is surprising and wierd. What is the latest error that you notice? Are you sure there is `/var/www` present in the image? Or do you want to try by creating it?

Comment: pwd -> /var/www/html. Hmmm, i'm using Docker For Mac. Apparently i should reinstall it...? '/var/www/html' is a common folder for php-apache. So it should be there since i'm using official docker image.

Comment: Did not get you. What is the later error with Approach #1 or #2? More over do you require file to be presented at `/var/www/html` instead of `/var/www`? Please clarify.

Comment: By both of ways, no error happened such as docker-compose failed to build. Just the expected files are missing. The top level of my project contains a `html` folder. So if i mount all sources to the `/var/www`, everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it appears that the `cp` command run through your Dockerfile's `RUN` instruction doesn't expect the second argument to be the destination file name.

Consider the following:

`RUN cp config.php.sample config.php`

> `config.php` is not found

It should not try to **find** `config.php`, but create it.

---

I reckon you'd probably be better off using:

`RUN mv config.php.sample config.php`

That will also delete your (now useless) `config.php.sample` file. Well, it won't delete nor create anything, simply rename your file -- which is exactly what you want `:)`

Comment: Actually, i was using `mv` before `cp`. But `mv` has a problem(It worked though) in case of when i'm going to docker-compose build&up again. Because the original file has been renamed and gone.

Comment: That is odd, to say the least. so `docker-compose build` modifies an already existing image instead of creating a new one? Or the `ADD` instruction somehow make all changes to the destination folder be reflected in their original location, on your local machine, outside your image? That sounds very wrong... Could you try that again, to make sure you didn't miss anything?

Comment: My docker images are sometimes going crazy, so i always remove images and containers before build. Removing command is 'docker rmi -f XXX' and i made sure the previous images were gone. For Containers, i use `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)`.